# Getting the column index by name when it follows a pattern

Tags: r

I have a dtaframe like below

```
lagged_1_FF, lagged_2_FF, lagged_1_HG,lagged_3_JK
1,2,3,NA
```

I wanto get the index of all columns which start with either lagged_1 or lagged_2

then I wanna drop them by subset command,

I can use grep command to delte one column but not a patter like above?

```
responseIndex=grep("outcome", colnames(data2))
trainData=subset(data2[(it+20):(it+40),],select=-c(responseIndex))
```

Comment: `new_data = data2[grep("lagged_1|lagged_2", x, invert = TRUE)]`

Comment: `library(dplyr); select(dat, -starts_with('lagged_1'), -starts_with('lagged_2'))`

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use grep() (but I prefer grepl()) with regular expressions to subset the data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  lagged_1_FF = 1, lagged_2_FF = 2, lagged_1_HG = 3, lagged_3_JK = NA
)

df[grep("^lagged_[12]", names(df))]
  lagged_1_FF lagged_2_FF lagged_1_HG
1           1           2           3
# Or if you prefer subset()
subset(df, select = grep("^lagged_[12]", names(df)))
```

But regular expressions are hard.. you could avoid them with something like this:

```
df[startsWith(names(df), c("lagged_1", "lagged_2"))]
# or
subset(df, select = startsWith(names(df), c("lagged_1", "lagged_2")))
```